# Jetpack Compose: MutableState<Boolean> not working as intended

Tags: android, kotlin, state, android-jetpack-compose

In our Android app we want to introduce Compose to a simple debug screen, where we can enable/disable SharedPreferences. I'm trying to get that running using Compose' interface `MutableState` - but it does not work how I think it does. My plan is to temporarily use `MutableState` to set a boolean in SharedPreferences (before migrating to DataStore later).

Here is what I had in mind:

```
private class MyOwnState(startWith: Boolean) : MutableState<Boolean> {
    override var value: Boolean = startWith
    override fun component1(): Boolean = value
    override fun component2(): (Boolean) -> Unit = { value = it }
}

// then, in composable:
var value by remember { MyOwnState(false) }
```

Of course in real life I would overwrite the getter+setter of the `value` - but this example is enough, because it does not work. The state change is not propagated and the UI is not updated.

To illustrate this, I but together the code snippets `by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }` and `by remember { MyOwnState(false) }`. The first one works (switch is updated), the second one does not.

Full code:

```
@Composable
fun SomeStateExamples() {
    Column {
        SwitchWorks()
        SwitchDoesNotWork()
    }
}

@Composable
fun SwitchWorks() {
    var value by remember { mutableStateOf(false) }
    Switch(checked = value, onCheckedChange = { value = it })
}

@Composable
fun SwitchDoesNotWork() {
    var value by remember { MyOwnState(false) }
    Switch(checked = value, onCheckedChange = { value = it })
}


private class MyOwnState(startWith: Boolean) : MutableState<Boolean> {
    override var value: Boolean = startWith
    override fun component1(): Boolean = value
    override fun component2(): (Boolean) -> Unit = { value = it }
}
```

The first switch is togglable, the second one is not:

[image: first switch works, second one does not]

What am I missing? The `MutableState` interface is pretty simple, and stable - and I didn't find any extra methods (aka invalidate, notifyListeners, ...) that I need to call.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 4):

Adding to Johan's answer, it looks like you also need to implement `StateObject` to fetch the value and update thd snapshot system. By having a look at `SnapshotMutableStateImpl`

```
override var value: T
        get() = next.readable(this).value
        set(value) = next.withCurrent {
            if (!policy.equivalent(it.value, value)) {
                next.overwritable(this, it) { this.value = value }
            }
        }

private var next: StateStateRecord<T> = StateStateRecord(value)

override val firstStateRecord: StateRecord
    get() = next
```

You will see that using `StateObject` makes you work with `StateRecord`s where you store the updatable value, read it and update it.

Answer (score 2):

In your `MyOwnState` class you have to implement private `mutableState` value like this:

```kotlin
private class MyOwnState(startWith: Boolean) : MutableState<Boolean> {
    private var _value by mutableStateOf(startWith)
    override var value: Boolean = startWith
        get() = _value
        set(value) {
            _value = value
            field = value
        }
    override fun component1(): Boolean = value
    override fun component2(): (Boolean) -> Unit = { value = it }
}
```

When you will try to change `value` inside composable, composition will recompose because you also changed MutableState `_value`. Read more about how state works in Jetpack Compose [here](https://dev.to/zachklipp/plumbing-data-with-derived-state-in-compose-53ka).

Comment: @mreichelt note that implementing a such class like  <@>Renattele exposed it, you don't need to embed its instance in a remember and you can share the instance over your views declaring it at top level (for instance).

Answer (score 1):

Not an answer directly, but looking at how `mutableStateOf` works, it's also calling `createSnapshotMutableState(value, policy)` behind the scenes.

So I don't think just inheriting `MutableState` and changing that will cause Compose to initiate a recomposition and thus updating the UI.

I would probably instead try to pass in the state of the UI from outside as a model with ViewModel or LiveData and mutate that model data.